# Negation of inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

So to my understanding, the negation of $\lt$ would be $\ge$. It's also my understanding that when you negate a false statement, it should be true (and vice versa).

But then I considered this simple situation:

Let a $\in \{0,1\}$
and b $\in \{1,2\}$

Clearly $a \lt b$ is false (i.e. when a = 1 and b = 1)

But the negation $a \ge b$ is also false (e.g. when a = 0 and b = 2)

The only correct inequality here $a \le b$, but I'm having a hard time trying to put into clear terms why this reasoning breaks down? In particular, in this case why does the negation of a false statement give another false statement?

(For context, I'm currently studying real analysis for the first time, and I've had a lot of proofs which involve inequalities. Through this example, I am starting to realise that maybe proof by contradiction/negation is not the best method when proving an inequality?)

Comment: $a< b$ means nothing. Instead, if you add quantifiers then it has sense. For example, $\exists a\in\{0,1\}\,\exists b\in\{1,2\}\colon a< b$ is true when $a=0$ and $b=1$ (for example). Another statement would be $\forall a\in\{0,1\}\,\forall b\in\{1,2\}\colon a<b$ is false when $a=1$ and $b=1$. But $a<b$ without quantifiers does not mean nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quantifiers whenever making statements.  $a<b$ by itself is meaningless. Here are two possible statements you could make:

> 1. $\forall a\in \{0,1\}$, $\forall b\in\{1,2\}$, $a<b$
> 2. $\exists a\in \{0,1\}$, $\exists b\in \{1,2\}$, $a<b$

Their negations are

> 3. $\exists a\in \{0,1\}$, $\exists b\in \{1,2\}$, $a\geq b$
> 4. $\forall a\in \{0,1\}$, $\forall b\in\{1,2\}$, $a\geq b$

Here, $(1)$ is false, $(2)$ is true, while $(3)$ is true and $(4)$ is false.

---

$\forall$ is the logical symbol for "for all" or "for each" or "for every", while $\exists$ is the logical symbol for "there exists" (and exists means "there exists atleast one", not "there exists a unique")

You mention real analysis, so you may have seen things like the triangle inequality: "$|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$". In the form currently stated, this is completely meaningless, because I haven't quantified $a$ and $b$. A meaningful statement (which is also true) is

> For every $a,b\in \Bbb{R}$, we have $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$ (with equality if and only if $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, or one of them is zero)

Its negation below is certainly false:

> There exist $a,b\in \Bbb{R}$ such that $|a+b| > |a|+|b|$.

The moral of the story is that yes it's true the negation of $<$ is $\geq$, but you also have to make explicit the quantifiers, and negate them.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense! Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem. You can upvote and accept the answer if it's satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements so the way to write possible inequalities is by quantifiers, then negations will work.

Let $A=\{0,1\},B=\{1,2\}$. For these sets

$\exists a\in A ~\forall b\in B~:~ a<b$
is a true statement. Its negation needs to be taken by de Morgan's laws.

Its negation is
$$\forall a\in A~\exists b\in B~:~a\geq b$$
which is a false statement.

Comment: I see! Thank you!